# Android: How to style the DatePicker?

Tags: android, datepicker, themes

I would like to style the DatePicker, but I cannot find how.

I would like to edit the layout (whose reference can be found here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/36f469fa46bd009bfbc27d1350af5bde4a4dd378/core/res/res/layout/date_picker_holo.xml), but internalLayout is not recognized by the Android Studio editor

```
<style name="MyDatePicker" parent="Widget.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:internalLayout">@android:layout/date_picker_holo</item>
</style>
```

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Starting API level 11 there is a [`datePickerStyle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#datePickerStyle) that allows some customization in tandem with `calendarViewShown`, `startYear`, `endYear`, `maxDate`, `minDate` and `spinnersShown`. However, if you want to fully customize the dialog/widgets, you'll probably find [this backport](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker) useful. If you include the latter, you can modify pretty much anything you like.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to recreate the layout with your own view and extend DatePicker. 
Check out this post [Custom DatePicker in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584934/custom-datepicker-in-android)