# DatePicker Dialogue Current Date Not getting to select

Tags: android, android-datepicker

Hi I am new Android developer. In my App, I have created `DatePickerDialogue`.

My problem is when I select any dates other than current date then current date is not able to select.

My Code:

```
public class DatePickerDialogue extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shared_layout);

    int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(DatePickerDialogue.this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                }

            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

    dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    dpd.show();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this way

In below code I have `OnclickListener` on `TextView` and set `Date` to the `TextView`.

```
   int mYear, mMonth, mDay;

      final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview23);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                                c.set(year, month, day);
                                String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(c.getTime());
                                textView.setText(date);

                                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

                Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();

                dpd.updateDate(d.get(Calendar.YEAR),d.get(Calendar.MONTH),d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                dpd.show();


            }

        });
```

### For Disable Future Date :

You should be able to call getDatePicker().[setMaxDate(long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate%28long%29) on your DatePickerDialog to set today as your max date. It will `disable` future `Date`.

#### Update :

for reset the `Date` whenever you want to default `Date` you have to update it is default value. like below code you can set it.

```
dpd.updateDate(d.get(Calendar.YEAR),d.get(Calendar.MONTH),d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115385/discussion-on-answer-by-ironman-datepicker-dialogue-current-date-not-getting-to).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
   Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
   int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    DatePickerDialog dp=new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }
    },year,month,day);
dp.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
 dp.show();
```

Comment: Can you check the system date(emulator or real device) whether its correct or not because same code works fine here

Comment: in real device,My system date is exactly fine and one more thing my dought u understand clearly?

Comment: when i open my datepicker dialogue by default it is showing current date

Comment: and when i select any other dates then i am not getting to select current date thst'w waht exactly my problem

Comment: step by step let me tell u first when we open DatePickerDialogue it's showing Current Date By default right? then user want to selected any other date other than current date ok user select one date other than current date then user want to select current data again but it is not getting to select please u observe this in ur device once i hope u understand clearly right?

Comment: May be custom date picker dialog will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584934/custom-datepicker-in-android